# Merge rows when same word appears in another column

Tags: r

I want to merge rows together that have the same word in another column. The table entries are all comma separated strings (characters), not lists. So as shown below the color shades for the same color should be added in a string in one row, instead of spanning over several rows. Also there should be no duplicates in the color shades column.

I have already tried with:

```
   aggregate(df["Color shades"], df["Color"], paste, collapse=", ")
```

As well as with:

```
   aggregate(Color shades ~ Color ,df ,toString)
```

But that didn't lead to the desired result.

Dataframe:

```
    df <- data.frame(colorshades = c("turquoise, babyblue", "royal blue, true blue", 
                         "navy blue, true blue"), colors = c("blue", "blue", "blue"))
```

Currently:

| Color shades | Color |
| --- | --- |
| turquoise, babyblue | blue |
| royal blue, true blue | blue |
| navy blue, true blue | blue |

Desired Output:

| Color shades | Color |
| --- | --- |
| turquoise, babyblue, royal blue, true blue, navy blue | blue |

Comment: Please post the output from dput(df) so people can work with the data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Convert `"Color shades"` to a list-column:

   ```r
   lapply(strsplit(df[["Color shades"]], ","), trimws)
   # [[1]]
   # [1] "turquoise" "babyblue" 
   # [[2]]
   # [1] "royal blue" "true blue" 
   # [[3]]
   # [1] "navy blue" "true blue"
   df[["Color shades"]] <- lapply(strsplit(df[["Color shades"]], ","), trimws)
   df
   #            Color shades Color
   # 1   turquoise, babyblue  blue
   # 2 royal blue, true blue  blue
   # 3  navy blue, true blue  blue
   ```
2. Aggregate with `unique`:

   ```r
   aggregate(df["Color shades"], df["Color"], function(z) paste(unique(unlist(z)), collapse=", "))
   #   Color                                          Color shades
   # 1  blue turquoise, babyblue, royal blue, true blue, navy blue
   ```

   or, keeping with the list-column method,

   ```r
   aggregate(df["Color shades"], df["Color"], function(z) list(unique(unlist(z))))
   #   Color                                          Color shades
   # 1  blue turquoise, babyblue, royal blue, true blue, navy blue
   str(aggregate(df["Color shades"], df["Color"], function(z) list(unique(unlist(z)))))
   # 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  2 variables:
   #  $ Color       : chr "blue"
   #  $ Color shades:List of 1
   #   ..$ : chr  "turquoise" "babyblue" "royal blue" "true blue" ...
   ```

There are often (but not always) advantages to dealing with list-columns vice comma-separated values. If your use-case is such that you frequently want to look at individual elements within one of these fields, you'll find yourself dealing deeply with regexes and/or repeatedly using `strsplit` to separate. With list-columns, one can use tools like `unique` and `%in%` with abandon (though admittedly one should really become more comfortable with `lapply`/`sapply`, and many base-R tools for aggregation do not always work consistently with list-columns).

---

Data

```r
df <- structure(list(`Color shades` = c("turquoise, babyblue", "royal blue, true blue", "navy blue, true blue"), Color = c("blue", "blue", "blue")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: if you use `", "` as split delimeter, you can drop the `lapply(..., trim_ws)`, and get the desired list directly from the output of `strsplit(df[["Color shades"]], ", ")`

Comment: valid point, but I wasn't certain on the quality of the data coming in with this example, so this covers situations where there may be missing spaces around the commas as well

Answer (score 0):

if you can use the library "dplyr" you can also do it this way :

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame("Colorshade" = c("turquoise, babyblue", "royal blue, true blue", "navy blue, true blue"),
             "Color" = c(rep("blue", 3)),
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

my_df <- df %>% group_by(Color) %>% mutate(Colorshade = paste(unique(sort(str_split(string = paste(df$Colorshade, collapse = ", "), pattern = ", ", simplify = TRUE))), collapse = ", ")) %>% first()
```

Answer (score 0):

`data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(Color_shades = paste0(unique(unlist(strsplit(colorshades, ", "))), 
                                    collapse = ", ")), 
          by = .(colors)]
#    colors                                          Color_shades
# 1:   blue turquoise, babyblue, royal blue, true blue, navy blue
```

Answer (score 0):

One can also use `tidytext` to with unnest

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)

color_df <- tibble(color= rep("blue", times = 3),
                       color_shades = c("turquoise, babyblue", "royal blue, true blue", "navy blue, true blue"))

color_shades_agg <- color_df %>% 
  unnest_tokens(word, color_shades, token = 'regex', pattern=", ") %>% 
  group_by(color) %>%
  distinct() %>% 
  summarise(color_shades = paste0(sort(word), collapse = ", "))
```